# CollectionViewで全体を縦にスクロール、行を横にスクロール、更に別の行にセルを移動できるようにするにはどうすればいいですか？

Tags: swift, xcode

auの「ビデオパス」アプリのように、全体は縦にスクロールでき、各行は横にスクロールできるというものをつくりたいのですが、
`CollectionView`ひとつでやるにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

`CollectionView`のセルに更に`CollectionView`を貼るという形にすれば、できるのですが、
ひとつの`CollectionView`でできるようにしたいです。
なぜなら、Sectionをまたいだセルの移動処理の実装がシンプルになるからです。

Section内のitem数に応じて、`sectionInset`を調整すると、Sectionの高さをitemと同じ高さにして、常に一行にすることはできるのですが、こうしただけだとitemのある部分がスクロールできません。itemのある部分だけを`bounce`できるようにできると良いのですが、方法が分かりません。

[image]

Answer (score 1):

UICollecitonViewのみでは実装できません。
UITableViewのCellにUICollectionViewのCellを配置しなければいけせん。

[image: イメージ]
詳しくはコチラ
Putting a UICollectionView in a UITableViewCell in Swift
https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

Comment: ありがとうございます！行をまたいだセルの移動は、UILongPressGestureRecognizerなどをつかって、当たり判定のような形でドラッグ中のセルとtableViewの行やセルとの重なりを判定するようなやり方で独自に実装するのが妥当でしょうか？

Comment: 行をまたいだセルの移動とはどういう意味ですか？

Comment: ドラッグして、ある行のセルを別の行に移動するということです。

Comment: http://himaratsu.hatenablog.com/entry/tableview/editmode

Comment: この辺を参考にしてください。 あとスタックオーバーフローでは、一つのページにつき1つの質問に限られますので、複数の質問を載せるのは辞めたほうがいいと思います